# Every intersection of an infinite number of open subspaces of $\Bbb C$ is also open - true or false?

Tags: general-topology

Assume

$$A_i \subset \Bbb C$$

is closed, such that

$$\Bbb C \setminus A_i $$

is open. I have to show that

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb C \setminus A_i$$

is either open or closed.

We already treated a similar case that worked like this:

$$(-\frac 1 n, 1 + \frac 1 n), n \ge 1$$

is open, but

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (-\frac 1 n, 1 + \frac 1 n) = [0, 1]$$

is closed. I wondered if I could simply use this case since we worked in $\Bbb R$ when we gave the example, and we didn't work with complements either then. (like we do in the task) And wouldn't this work the exact same way not only for intersections, but also for unions?

Comment: It could be neither open nor closed. The intersections of the open circles of radius $1+\frac1n$ centered at $1/n$ for $n \in \Bbb N$ is the unit circle containing all its boundary points except for $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the intersection of the open disks about the origin having all radii greater than $1$. This will yield a non-open (in fact, closed) intersection of infinitely-many open sets. Another, similar example comes from taking the intersection of the open disks about the origin of all positive radii.

An infinite union of open sets is still open. However, an infinite union of closed sets need not be closed, and any counterexample that works in the reals also works in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

The counter-example of $\mathbb{R}$ extends to $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $\Re : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the real-part projection.  It is continuous.

Let $I_n = (-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})$.  Then, since $\Re$ is continuous, $\Re^{-1}(I_n)$ is open.  But since $[0,1]$, is closed $\mathbb{R}\setminus[0,1]$ is open and so is $\Re^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus[0,1]) = \Re^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\setminus \Re^{-1}([0,1]) = \mathbb{C} \setminus \Re^{-1}([0,1])$.  Thus $\Re^{-1}([0,1])$ is closed.

But $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*} \Re^{-1}(I_n) = \Re^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*} I_n\right) = \Re^{-1}([0,1]) $$, so this is an intersection of open sets that is a non-open set itself.

On the contrary, the union of open sets is always open, else you wouldn't have a well-defined topology.